# Electric field at $r=0$

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, singularities

How does classical physics justify the existence of an electric field at $r=0$?

Is this an edge case, an ambiguity, a "does not exist"?

Is this a trivial case or indicative of an actual fault in classical electrodynamics?

Obviuosly the math breaks down because the denominator is $r^2$...What I want to know, is this significant or a trivial case?

Comment: The force goes like $1/r^2$ for two point-like charges very far away from each other: once the charges approach, their sizes and the charge distributions come into play and the field is more than regular at $r=0$.

Answer (score -1):

To make it simple, it does not exist, there are no real point-like classical charged particles. That's why we learn, for example, the electric field of a homogeneous charged sphere right after the one for a point charge.

To put it in another way. A point charge $e$ could be thought of as made up by many $de$ tiny charges at one spot, but you'll require an infinite amount of energy to bring two (or more) of these charges from infinity to a single and the same point.

Comment: Point particles has problems with causality too. The self-interaction during a constant force into the body leads to action before the cause, advanced acceleration (see [Griffiths](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=J9ygBwAAQBAJ&dq=griffiths+electrodynamics&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAGoVChMIwqO3z9XRyAIVgx4eCh0lPA97), pg. 467).
Conclusion: The awareness of very tiny point charge concentration leads to quantum mechanics?

Comment: @Nogueira see also http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/208799/is-it-possible-to-push-together-two-charged-particles-of-the-same-charge-hard-en

Comment: Ow. GR came first! But who know what is happening inside a block hole?

Comment: Note that exactly the same thing occurs with all the 1/r² laws, from gravity to vorticity.